# Export image Cross to canvas (google-store)

Tags: image, canvas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cross-domain

I need to add a google-store image to canvas. But adding the "crossOrigin" attribute to the image is giving error.
Without the attribute it works.
Example:
[image: Screenshot of code]

Comment: please post your code in text here, the formatting tools will make it look nice and it is easier to reply to or reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your bucket or object cors policy look like?

You can verify if it is correctly using the following command:

```
gsutil cors get gs://example-bucket
```

I see you are trying to set it to anonymous, which I think may not be the correct way to do this. If you want all domains to access your bucket then you might have to set it to `*`. But you need to do this in the bucket or bucket object itself. For setting the cors header across all objects in a bucket you can use the following command:

```
gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://example-bucket
```

where cors-json-file.json contents should look like:

```
[
    {
      "origin": ["http://example.appspot.com"],
      "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
      "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE"],
      "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
    }
]
```

See: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors